# How to print objects from a TreeSet

Tags: java, iterator, treeset

I want to print the instance variables of the objects I stored in my TreeSet.

So given an Object with three instance variables, I want to iterate over the Objects in my TreeSet and print their ivars but:

```
while ( iter.hasNext() )
{
  System.out.println( iter.next().getIvar1 );
  System.out.println( iter.next().getIvar2 );
}
```

gets me the ivar1 of the first object and the ivar2 of the second object.
And with all my searching I found no way of printing all the ivars of one object before moving the iterator to the next object like:

```
while ( iter.hasNext() )
{
  System.out.println( iter.hasNext().getIvar1() );
  System.out.println( iter.getIvar2 );
  System.out.println( iter.getIvar3 );
  System.out.println( iter.hasNext().getIvar1() );
  ....
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement that?

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
for (Element element : set) {
    System.out.println(element.getIvar1());
    System.out.println(element.getIvar2());
}
```

Internally, it's just an iterator - but it saves you the trouble of manually calling `next()` and `hasNext()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep calling `iter.next()` inside the loop. Only call it once. Every time you call [`Iterator.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29), it advances the iterator to the next element in the iteration.

```
while ( iter.hasNext() )
{
    Foo element = iter.next();
  System.out.println( element.getIvar1 );
  System.out.println( element.getIvar2 );
}
```